# Updating a value in an interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to have a function update its value on its next interval.

```
/*jshint esversion: 6*/
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const db = require('../../config/db');

module.exports = class Battle extends commando.Command {
  constructor(client) {
    super(client, {
      name: 'battle',
      aliases: ['fight'],
      group: 'actions',
      memberName: 'battle',
      description: 'What mob to battle.',
      args: [
        {
          key: 'mob',
          prompt: 'What mob do you want to attack? Mob ID only!',
          type: 'integer',
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  run(msg, { mob }) {
    var times = 0;
    var clearBattle = false;
    var mobs = null;
    var userData = msg.member.user; // Set user variable

    var userSQL = 'SELECT * FROM users_meta WHERE userid = ?';
    db.query(userSQL, userData.id, (err, row) => { // User Query
      if (row[0] === undefined) { // If user is not registered, kill process.
        return msg.channel.send('You are not registered!');
      } else {
        userData.game = row[0];
        var mobSQL = 'SELECT * FROM mobs WHERE id = ?';
        db.query(mobSQL, mob, (err, row) => { // Mob Query
          if (row[0] === undefined) { // if mob doesnt exist, kill process.
            return msg.channel.send('That mob doesn\'t exist');
          } else { // If registered and mob exists, start the battle and assign mob
            mobs = row[0];
            if (userData.interval === undefined || userData.interval === false) {
              userData.interval = setInterval(() => {
                battle(mob);
              }, 6000);
              battle(mob);
            } else {
              return mob;
            }
          }



          // Start battle loop function
          function battle(mob) {
            db.query(userSQL, userData.id, (err, row) => {
              userData.game = row[0];
            });

            console.log(mob);
            if (times < 10) {
              msg.channel.send('Six Seconds for ' + userData.username +
              '(' + userData.game.str + ')' + '. Fighting mob ' + mobs.name + '(' + mobs.id + ').');
              times++;
            } else {
              clearInterval(userData.interval);
              userData.interval = false;
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

};
```

As it stands: 
!battle 1 (will fight said mob)

However if I want to change mobs `!battle 2` it would then change the value of of well... everything inside the `battle()` function. I don't have any calculations based on the mob id yet, so maybe its not quite clear what I want.

EDIT: I'm still struggling. I'm trying everything. It would be easy if I just cleared the interval and just created it again, but I want it to wait for the repeat to update the information.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer:

```
    if (userData.interval === undefined || userData.interval === false) {
      userData.interval = setInterval(() => {
        battle(mob);
        userData.intervalTime = Date.now();
      }, 6000);
      battle(mob);
    } else {
      var timing = userData.intervalTime + 5900 - Date.now();
      if (timing < 0) {
        timing = 0;
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        clearInterval(userData.interval);
        userData.interval = setInterval(() => {
          battle(mob);
          userData.intervalTime = Date.now();
        }, 6000);
        battle(mob);
      }, timing);
    }
```